# After GIT commit, I did GIT push but the message said everything up-to-date

Tags: linux, git, push, commit

I'm new to Git. We're in Linux, and I just inherited someone's project family.

I recently did:

```
git add Bom.xml Bom.csv N.cpp makefile ../mm
git commit -a
```

(said On branch Bom, your branch is ahead of master by 2 commits. use git push to publish your local commits. Untracked files: list of things I don't want to commit anyway). Nothing added to commit but untracked files present.

then

```
git push
```

But it said everything up-to-date. I'm not sure where to look to see that my content is pushed up to my branch on the server.  I know I had file changes since my last commit.  It's a tough thing to search for the answer online. I looked at [up-to-date too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921293/git-push-returns-everything-up-to-date), and added the git add and the -a to my commit, but it still says up-to-date when I try to push.

Thanks!
Mich

Comment: So, after adding a new file/editing, if you do `git diff` it should show edited/new files, and if you do `git add *` and `git commit` and then `git push` .. it should work just fine :D

Comment: I added a new file (junk.xml.good) and saved in eclipse.  Then I did a git diff at the command line and it didn't show anything.

Comment: After that I tried git add * and it says the following paths are ignored by .gitignore files: with some .o, .so, and a library and says fatal: no files added.

Comment: Then I tried mv junk.xml.good junk.xml just in case it was being ignored, and git diff didn't pick anything up, git add* said the same thing as last time, listing the .o and .so, and library as being ignored and fatal: no files added.

Comment: Maybe you need to look into your .gitignore then, if it ignores the files/folders you add things to.

Comment: Any idea where .gitignore would be?

Comment: It is probably located in the root folder of your project, .gitignore, in Linux this would be a hidden file so you use `ls -la` (for example) to list those kind of files.

Comment: It might also be helpful to share the output of `$ git log`, `$ git branch -v`, and `$ git status`.

Comment: Make sure to try by specifying both the remote and the branch, e.g. `git push origin Bom`. It’s possible that your push settings are set up, so a simple `git push` won’t try to push your current branch.

Comment: @palimpsestor - I can't paste in here, but when I do a git log, June 3 I see my commit for Fixing a margin error.  May 15 I see a commit for feature/spec/code changes.  I'm not seeing anything for the pushes I tried.

Comment: @palimpsestor - Git branch -v shows * Bom [ahead 2] fixed margin error, then a couple other branches including master. git status says on branch Bom, your branch is ahead of master by 2 commits. (use git push to publish your local commits) Changes to be committed: new file: junk.xml, untracked files: <list of junky files .good, .old, .comments. .swp>.  I had added and changed some other files and I'm hoping they are pushed to master but I'm not sure.

Comment: @poke - would "git push origin Bom" push my local branch Bom to the Bom branch on origin/master? I don't want to release yet.  Just do a intermediate push of what I have.

Comment: No, it would push to the tracking branch, which should be `Bom`. You can use `git push origin Bom:Bom` to be *very* explicit.

Comment: That seems to have worked.  git push origin Bom:Bom.  It Compressed, Wrote objects.  100%, 14 in all, to the productName.git on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [link you mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23921757/1820217), make sure you have added the file you want to commit into the `staging area`. Each time you want to commit

- run `git status` to check.
- And then run `git add file` to add file to `staging area`.
- Run `git status` to check whether the file is added to the stage.
- Then run `git commit -m "some message"` to commit
- run `git log` to check your commit history check whether you have committed successfully
- then check your remote branch by running `git branch -a`
- if your remote branch doesn't have your local branch `branch-name`
- then run `git push origin branch-name` to push your local branch to remote.

Comment: when you say git push origin branch-name, is that what I need?  When my predecessor was leaving, he had me create the branch in eclipse, rt-click the product name ->team->switchTo->new branch Source->select->master and give it Branch Name: Bom.  Does that mean I should do a "git push master Bom" instead of origin?

Comment: Do you have a remote repo? run `git remote -v` to check the remote rep. And `git push origin branch-name" is just publish your local branch to remote